# How to find JSON in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, json

How can I  find a value within a JSON array in MySQL? I am trying this option

https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/df842fcbe7d246262b65740c80668c4e/

```
create table tbl (id int, home json);

insert into tbl values 
(1, '[
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
]');

select * 
from tbl
where json_contains(home, '1');
```

but there are no results.

Comment: You're missing a double quote ("") around 1. This should work: 
**_select * from tbl where json_contains(home, '"1"');_**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows using `JSON_CONTAINS` :

```
select * 
from tbl
where JSON_CONTAINS(home, '"1"', '$');
```

PS : "1" is a string so you have to use double quotes.

This is an other way to do it using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) :

```
select *
from tbl 
where JSON_SEARCH(home, 'one', "1") is not null
```

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)

Comment: Please tell me more, for some reason it does not work in PHP through mysqli_query.

Comment: Error: $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * from products where JSON_SEARCH(json, "one", "361")');

Comment: You will need to escape double quotes